# 2 DateTimes are getting editted by 1

Tags: php, datetime

Ok i got a weird issue here.
Im trying to calculate the old date and the new date. However i spotted a issue that is unexplainable by me.

**The setup :**
I have 2 new dates set on today.

```
$tempstamp = new DateTime();
$newstamp = new DateTime();
```

Now, i edit the newstamp into a new date useing :

```
if ($newstamp ->format('His') > 120000) $newstamp ->modify('+7 day');
else $newstamp ->modify('+4 day');
```

Which works perfectly. However now comes the weird part.
When i dump both values before and after it the tempstamp gives a unexplainable value :

```
case '2':
  $tempstamp = $newstamp;

  dump($tempstamp->format('m-d')); // 02-19 - CORRECT
  dump($newstamp->format('m-d')); // 02-19 - CORRECT

  if ($newstamp->format('His') > 120000) $newstamp->modify('+7 day');
  else $newstamp->modify('+4 day');

  dump($tempstamp->format('m-d')); // 02-26 - FALSE
  dump($newstamp->format('m-d')); // 02-26 - CORRECT
```

*NOTE: dump is our way of var_dumping*

**The Question:**
Can someone explain why tempstamp is getting editted as well while i only edit newstamp?

Comment: Because objects are assigned by reference in PHP. After `$tempstamp = $newstamp`, both variables point to the same object.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PHP copies objects by reference, not by value](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php). So `$tempstamp = $newstamp;` is now making `$tempstamp` and `$newstamp` point to the same object. To avoid this you need to use `clone`:

`$tempstamp = clone $newstamp;`